# How to Rotate Only One View Controller to Landscape Orientation in iOS Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

you can find more Answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50126802/5200447

Answer (score 5):

This is for **Swift3 and Swift 4**.
You can use the follow code in your AppDelegate.swift :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    guard let rootViewController = self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: window?.rootViewController),
     (rootViewController.responds(to: Selector(("canRotate")))) else{
        // Only allow portrait (standard behaviour)
        return .portrait;
    }
    // Unlock landscape view orientations for this view controller
    return .allButUpsideDown;
}

private func topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: UIViewController!) -> UIViewController? {
    guard rootViewController != nil else { return nil }

    guard !(rootViewController.isKind(of: (UITabBarController).self)) else{
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: (rootViewController as! UITabBarController).selectedViewController)
    }
    guard !(rootViewController.isKind(of:(UINavigationController).self)) else{
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: (rootViewController as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController)
    }
    guard !(rootViewController.presentedViewController != nil) else{
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: rootViewController.presentedViewController)
    }
    return rootViewController
}
```

you can learn more in the original post: http://www.jairobjunior.com/blog/2016/03/05/how-to-rotate-only-one-view-controller-to-landscape-in-ios-slash-swift/