# Swift: Previous view rotated while fading to a view that has a different orientation

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, transform, autorotate, catransition

My previous view (**CaptureVC**) doesn't autorotate, so it only has a portrait orientation. My second view that it transitions into (**ManageCaptureVC**) does autorotate, and while it is doing a fading transition into it, CaptureVC is suddenly rotated while fading if the device is in landscape. How can this be avoided or compensated for?

To be more thorough, it is a scaling animation, then a fading animation into the new view controller (**ManageCaptureVC**):

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.75, y: 0.75)
}, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
    // Here is where CaptureVC rotates while fading into ManageCaptureVC
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)
    self.present(manageCaptureVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
})
```

In my app delegate, I overrode these two functions:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if let rootViewController = self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: window?.rootViewController) {
        if (rootViewController.responds(to: Selector(("canRotate")))) {
            // Unlock landscape view orientations for this view controller if it is not currently being dismissed
            if !rootViewController.isBeingDismissed{
                return .all
            }
        }
    }

    // Only allow portrait (standard behaviour)
    return .portrait
}

private func topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: UIViewController!) -> UIViewController? {
    if (rootViewController == nil) {
        return nil
    }
    if (rootViewController.isKind(of: UITabBarController.self)) {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: (rootViewController as! UITabBarController).selectedViewController)
    } else if (rootViewController.isKind(of: UINavigationController.self)) {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: (rootViewController as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController)
    } else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController != nil) {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: rootViewController.presentedViewController)
    }
    return rootViewController
}
```

And **ManageCaptureVC** I added:

```
@objc func canRotate(){}
```

So that it so it responds to autorotating.

Comment: Check this Answer. it's possible help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41702940/how-to-rotate-only-one-view-controller-to-landscape-orientation-in-ios-swift-3/41702941#41702941

Comment: Both orientation options work for both view controllers, it’s just the fading transition that looks messed up, possibly because it captures an image of the current view controller, rotates the second view, then fades.

Comment: That answer looks to be almost identical to what I'm using in my question. I updated the question with the other part I'm using in my delegate which is the same as in that link.